# Calculating and printing the sums of the diagonals of a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

This is a program that is supposed to calculate the sum of all the diagonals in the matrix and then print them out.

ex. if the matrix is

1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6
0  1  1  2  5
5  5  5  5  5
7  8  9  7  7

the output should be

17  13  13  10  5

15  17  13  13  10

14  15  17  13  13

13  14  15  17  13

7  13  14  15  17

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, sum=0, i, j, sub_i, sub_j, sub1_i, sub1_j;

    scanf("%d ", &n);

    int array1[n][n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            sub_i=i;
            sub_j=j;
            sub1_i=i;
            sub1_j=j;
            sum=0;

            if(j>i){
                while(sub_j<n){
                    sum+=array1[sub_i][sub_j];
                    sub_i++;
                    sub_j++;
                }
                while(sub_j<n){
                    array1[sub_i][sub_j]=sum;
                    sub1_i++;
                    sub1_j++;
                }
            }

            if(i>j){
                while(sub_i<n){
                    sum+=array1[sub1_i][sub1_j];
                    sub_i++;
                    sub_j++;
                }
                while(sub1_i<n){
                    array1[sub1_i][sub1_j]=sum;
                    sub1_i++;
                    sub1_j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%d ", array1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the program it prints the array as if no value was assigned to the matrix. Can someone point out what is happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The program alters the array it is examining — see `array1[sub_i][sub_j]=sum;` — and then prints incorrect values, since you can't correctly sum the diagonals of an array that is changing.

Comment: @WeatherVane so what you are telling me is to assign the values to another array and print that

Comment: You are calculating only the lef-to-right diagonals. What a bout the right-to-left diagonals?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Looking at the OP's desired input and output (at start of post), it seems he starts at the longest (1 - 7) diagonal, brushes upwards to 5, then starts again at the "2 - 7" diagonal, and brushes down to 7.  It's a little bit of an odd question.  And yes, as you say, it ignores left to right diagonals.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the program should only calculate the sum of the right to left diagonals and print them in the order above. I didn't mention that my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the comment by [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane):

> The program alters the array it is examining — see `array1[sub_i][sub_j]=sum;` — and then prints incorrect values, since you can't correctly sum the diagonals of an array that is changing.

The OP already realize that

> ... what you are telling me is to assign the values to another array and print that.

Yes, that is way easier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    // Checking the input is always a good idea, but you
    // may prefer something less brutal, in case of error
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1  ||  n < 1)
       return 1;    

    int mat[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j= 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1; 
        }
    }

    // Calculate and store the sum of the diagonals. Note that
    // it could be done in the previous loop, but it may be better
    // to refactor those snippets into separate functions.
    int diagonals[2 * n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n + 1; ++i)
        diagonals[i] = 0;  // consider 'memset' instead of this loop

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            diagonals[n + i - j] += mat[i][j]; 
        }    
    }

    // Now print the correct values in their position
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            printf("%4d", diagonals[n + i - j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j8IFGjoRHj1rRMY5).

Comment: what is `memeset` ?

Comment: @Spyware It's a library function defined in `<string.h>` which can be used to initialize a block of memory: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main()
{
  int array[N][N] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
    0, 1, 1, 2, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    7, 8, 9, 7, 7};

  for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 1; j < N; ++j)
      array[i][j] += array[i - 1][j - 1];

  for (int i = 0; i + 1 < N; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j + 1 < N; ++j)
      if (i == j)
        array[i][j] = array[N - 1][N - 1];
      else if (i > j)
        array[i][j] = array[N - 1][N - 1 - i + j];
      else
        array[i][j] = array[N - 1 - j + i][N - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but your answer lacks any explanation of what problem(s) you found in the OP's code and why what you did is the desired fix (even commenting the code would help).